# How to merger the splited data into same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table having data like this

```
id | Name | Age
---------------
 1 | a,b  | 10
```

I want to split that data and merge with the same table like this

```
id | Name | Age
---------------
 1 | a    | 10
 1 | b    | 10
```

I have a split function.

Comment: Do you use MySQL or MS SQL Server or do you want a solution that works for both?

Comment: Thanks for the response, i am using sql server

Comment: [In the up-right side there is a textbox for search.](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server%5D+concatenate+strings)

Answer (score 1):

### Test Data

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(id INT, Name VARCHAR(10), Age INT)
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
 (1 ,'a',10), (1 ,'b',10),
 (2 ,'d',20), (2 ,'f',20)
```

### Query

```
 SELECT t.ID
        ,STUFF(( SELECT ',' + Name
                 FROM @TABLE
                 WHERE ID = t.ID AND Age = t.Age
                 FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
                 .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'') AS Name
       ,t.Age

FROM @TABLE t
GROUP BY t.id, t.Age
```

### Result

```
╔════╦══════╦═════╗
║ ID ║ Name ║ Age ║
╠════╬══════╬═════╣
║  1 ║ a,b  ║  10 ║
║  2 ║ d,f  ║  20 ║
╚════╩══════╩═════╝
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that OP has the data concatenated and needs to split it.  Here's one way to do it (fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6b2a1/15)

```
WITH cteSplitCol
AS
(
  SELECT  id,
          Name,
          Age,
          SUBSTRING(Name, 1, 1) AS Character,
          1 AS CharPos,
          MAX(LEN(Name)) OVER () AS MaxLen
  FROM    Table1

  UNION ALL

  SELECT  id,
          Name,
          Age,
          SUBSTRING(Name, CharPos + 1, 1) AS Character,
          CharPos + 1,
          MaxLen
  FROM    cteSplitCol
  WHERE   CharPos + 1 <= MaxLen
)

SELECT  id,
        Character AS Name,
        Age
FROM    cteSplitCol
WHERE   Character <> ',';
```